# Probability the addition rule depending on events

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand something about the addition rule. It might be very very basic. I tried to search for it but I might not know the correct words in english for this.
I am trying to understand if it is true that:
$$P(A\cup B|C)=P(A|C)+P(B|C)-P(A\cap B|C)$$

thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried to maybe get to it in some other way but I couldnt

Comment: Draw a venn diagram which in which A, B and C overlap and see for yourself! (It is true).

Comment: I actually did that and I thought it was true but it didnt workout with some exercises i received. Thank you!!

Comment: should i delete this question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclusion-exclusion principle [for probabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability)  is used to reason about probabilities of union of events and so on.

In your case, all the events, $A \cup B, A, B, A \cap B $ are **all** conditioned on C, but still are events with corresponding probabilities.

Thus, there is no reason that the law will not hold.

You can use the venn diagram to convince yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We would like to show that $P(A \cup B \mid C)$ and 
$P(A \mid C) + P(B \mid C) - P(A \cap B \mid C)$ are equal.

This will be a proof by direct calculation.
Assume $P(C)\neq 0$ so that the conditional probabilities are well-defined.

Consider the two events $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$.
Apply the formula for the (unconditioned) probability of the
union of these two events:

$$P((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)) = 
   P(A \cap C) + P(B \cap C) - P((A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C)). \tag{1}$$

By DeMorgan's Laws, $(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap C.$
Moreover, by associativity and commutativity of intersection,
$(A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap (C \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap C.$
So we can rewrite Equation $(1)$:

$$P((A \cup B) \cap C) = 
   P(A \cap C) + P(B \cap C) - P((A \cap B) \cap C).$$

Use the fact that $P(X \cap C) = P(X \mid C) P(C)$ for any event $X$
to rewrite this equation again:

$$P((A \cup B) \mid C) P(C) = 
   P(A \mid C) P(C) + P(B \mid C) P(C) - P((A \cap B) \mid C) P(C).$$

Now, using the assumption that $P(C)\neq 0$, we can divide both
sides of the equation by $P(C)$:

$$P((A \cup B) \mid C) = P(A \mid C) + P(B \mid C) - P((A \cap B) \mid C).$$

QED